# Angular 15 Standalone AppComponent and AngularFireAuth

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular15, angular-standalone-components

I am trying to set up an Angular webapp where the AppComponent is standalone itself using Firebase Authentication (and database). Therefore no `NgModule`s.

I added in the main.ts

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),

    ),
    importProvidersFrom(
      provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
    ),
  ...
  ]
```

And in the AppComponent I added the other imports:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
```

I don't have any specific error, but once I try to inject in the constructor `AngularFireAuth` I get the following error:

[image]

I have also tried to add

```
importProvidersFrom(AngularFireAuthModule),
```

in the providers of the `main.ts` but it didn't help.

Does anyone know how I might solve this issue or know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `InjectionToken('angularfire2.app.options')` is provided in the [AngularFireModule](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/b36b6a7e2e1a829e543656313b55a3732edc7108/src/compat/firebase.app.module.ts#L50) module, not in the `AngularFireAuthModule`.

To resolve the issue, the [AngularFireModule.initializeApp()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/b36b6a7e2e1a829e543656313b55a3732edc7108/src/compat/firebase.app.module.ts#L51) should be used with the [importProvidersFrom](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#configuring-dependency-injection) in the `main.ts`:

```js
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    // ...
  ]
})
```

Comment: And instead for add also Firestore functionality, what is the correct provider? Do you have any suggestions on where should I look up Firebase documentation with standalone components?